# Unable to access innert html tag webdriver

Tags: html, selenium-webdriver, tags

I'm having problems trying to access an object that is inside in a `iframe` tag.

here is the `html`:

[image: ![html]

and this is my code:

```
System.out.println(Utils.existElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@name='popupFrame' and @src='/npa-contratacion/layout/error.jsp?SESSION_CLIENT_STATE=popupFrame']")));
```

the results is true , but , for example, when i type this:

```
System.out.println(Utils.existElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@name='popupFrame' and @src='/npa-contratacion/layout/error.jsp?SESSION_CLIENT_STATE=popupFrame']//body")));
```

The result is false.

any suggestions?

The problem is that in the DOM, there are two popUpsFrames with the same `id`, One inside another.

[first one][2]
[second one][3]

if i write:

```
driver.switchTo().frame("popupFrame");
driver.switchTo().frame("popupFrame");
System.out.println(Utils.existElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@name='popupFrame' and @src='/npa-contratacion/layout/error.jsp?SESSION_CLIENT_STATE=popupFrame']//body")));
```

Im recieving a `NoSuchFrameException`.

Comment: You need to switch to that `iframe` first to be able to handle elements inside it

Comment: Thanks Andersson but the dom hav two popUpsFrames with the same id

Comment: In this case you can use `index` or bound to parent `div`: `//div[@id="popupInner"]/iframe`

Comment: Thanks, it works.